# Can a forwarding rule be set on Outlook that will not be visible on office365/exchange admin interface?

Tags: email, incident-response, exchange, outlook

In an incident concerning a user's mailbox - will any rule that forwards emails to a potential attack be visible in the office365/exchange admin interface, or is it possible to set an outlook client-only rules that will forward these emails and will not show unless inspecting the user's outlook client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally there are multiple Ways to forward E-Mails:

- Users can create a forwarding rule within Outlook or Outlook Web App
- An administrator can create a client rule for forwarding
- An administrator can set the ForwardingSMTPAddress parameter on a mailbox
- Users can set the ForwardingSMTPAddress parameter on a mailbox
- An administrator can set the ForwardingAddress parameter on a mailbox

You can check which Mailboxes have external forwarding enabled via Powershell, as [this](https://www.dynamicconsulting.com/office-365-email-forwarding-security-gap/) Post suggests.

`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {(RecipientTypeDetails -ne "DiscoveryMailbox") -and ((ForwardingSmtpAddress -ne $null) -or (ForwardingAddress -ne $null))}`

If you want to disable external forwarding of Mails in General, [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/stop-auto-forwarding-emails-in-microsoft-365-f9d693ba-5c78-47c0-b156-8e461e062aa7) Microsoft Guide will help you.